# ACF field check value of field on all other articles

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions

I am looking to implement a basic check on my ACF field. I have an ACF field called  `Featured Article` on all my custom post-type articles. It's a simple switch allowing for `on`, `off` functionality. I want to allow a max of 3 articles at the same time with the `on` setting, to display at most 3 articles to the user on the front-end.

For this functionality I have to write some code that checks for the setting on the backend on all the articles. For example, when the user is on a fourth article and switches the select of the ACF to `on`, there should be an error of sorts that says "you already have three other articles selected. Ideally, it would somehow gather the titles of the other articles and allow a quick switch-off for those.

I understand that this would be adding a lot of custom features to the WP backend, so let's start with the basics. How do I enable the ACF field to cross-check for the value of all other articles?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to do it would be using the `save_post` [action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post).  Since your article isn't being saved through AJAX, and only when you actually save the post, that would be the best place, in my opinion.

I honestly haven't written a lot of error messages, so this might be wonky and probably won't work out of the gate, but I started with [this article from SitePoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/displaying-errors-from-the-save_post-hook-in-wordpress/).

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_post_function' );
function my_save_function( $post_id ) {
    $error = false;

    $featured = get_posts(array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'featured_article',
                'compare' => '=',
                'value' => '1'
            )
        )
    ));

    if ( count($featured) > 3 ) {
        $error = new WP_Error('too_many_featured_articles', 'There are too many featured articles.');
        // You could use this error to list the titles and links to edit all of the other current featured articles.
    }

    if ($error) {
        // Here is where you would unset the ACF field, if you wanted.
    }

    return true;
}
```

This isn't meant to get you through the whole thing, but hopefully it's a good starting point for you.